# Login to Customer Account with Ajax Form

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify

Could you let me know if there's anything in the Shopify backend preventing me from including an ajax login form on our site? Basically I want customers to be able to login from anywhere.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/account/login" id="customer_login" method="post" class="cd-form">
<input name="form_type" type="hidden" value="customer_login">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">


<p class="fieldset">
<label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
<input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="customer_email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="customer[email]">
<span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
</p>

<p class="fieldset">
<label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signin-password">Passwort</label>
<input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="customer_password" type="password"  placeholder="Password" name="customer[password]">
<span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
</p>

<p class="fieldset">
<input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" checked>
<label for="remember-me">Angemeldet bleiben</label>
</p>

<p class="fieldset">
<input class="full-width" type="submit" value="Anmelden">
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you pleae share a bit the context of this?

Comment: I like to show the customer registration form in a popup. Link to my Project: http://printnil.com/

Comment: Why don't you use the whole CMS as well as ecommerce in Shopify? Shopify site structure as well as frontend options + backend (liquid) are tremendous, so besides of your question itself which we can answer after finding out where you are, we'd suggest moving all the content to shopify. See a website which is 0% ecommerce and has only pages + blog which looks pretty good: http://www.microapps.com/

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late, but this is **completely possible to do**. It's kind of complicated, but very doable.

In short, you need to do this:

1. Send an ajax POST request to `/account/login`
2. Scan the HTML response to check for login errors
3. Redirect the customer if required

Providing a full solution here is too long for StackOverflow - check out the blog post I've written up on this for more details: http://inside.sauce.ly/how-to-build-an-ajax-login-form-on-shopify/

**Worth noting:** this approach is not actively supported by Shopify.